# Centering bootstrap wells with horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap wells to make a type of card display that needs to go from the left to the right (horizontal), but for some reason the wells only want to be aligned vertically.

```css
body {
  background-color: #5C67B6;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5C67B6;
  border-color: #5C67B6;
  /*set the color you want here*/
}

.btn-purple:hover,
.btn-purple:focus,
.btn-purple:active,
.btn-purple.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4b5496;
  border-color: #4b5496;
  /*set the color you want here*/
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container content-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8">
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
          <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
          <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="well">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
          <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
          <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you check the snippet, you'll see that it's all being positioned vertically after each individual well is placed in. I'm using inline-block for the container and have tried using it for the well with no luck. How can I make it align horizontally?

Comment: So you're wanting the wells to be side-by-side, instead of on top of each other?

Comment: @Nieminen yes exactly. I was told to use inline-block to achieve this which isn't working.

Comment: Are you alright with each well being the same width?

Comment: @Nieminen maybe for now, but probably not for later. Include it in the answer as an optional choice.

Comment: Also, is there a reason your setting your containing column to sm-8 and md-4? Just to make sure I'm covering all possible answers

Comment: @Nieminen that was just one way i was resizing the wells.

Comment: @Nieminen i'm also trying to have it display 2 of them at a time, then go to the next line and display another 2. So.. two wells then it goes under and displays another 2 wells.

Comment: Just posted an answer that I believe does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First easy option is to just use cols inside your main col, where each well is a .col-md-6 .col-xs-12 or something like that.

the snippets below should do what I think you're describing.

```css
body {
  background-color: #5C67B6;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5C67B6;
  border-color: #5C67B6;
  /*set the color you want here*/
}

.btn-purple:hover,
.btn-purple:focus,
.btn-purple:active,
.btn-purple.active,
.open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-purple {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4b5496;
  border-color: #4b5496;
  /*set the color you want here*/
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
<div class="container content-sm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
                <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
                <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
                <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
                <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
                <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
                <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="well">
                <img class="center-block" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" style="border-radius: 50%;" height="80" width="80">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Test!</h3>
                <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-purple btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Join server!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks. this works well. is there any way to make them smaller but with the same functionality? (2x2)

Comment: Couple ways. most versatile would probably just be throwing a custom class on your first div, something like this... `.customClass { width: 700px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0px auto; }`